# What is the $L^2$ gradient flow?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What does $L^2$ gradient flow mean? Here is the Ginzburg–Landau free
energy:
$$\mathcal{E}(\phi):=\int_{\Omega}(F(\phi)+\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}|\nabla\phi|^2)\text{d}\mathbf{x}$$
Some references say the Allen-Cahn equation 
$$\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t} =
{\epsilon^2}\Delta\phi(\mathbf{x},t)-F'(\phi(\mathbf{x},t))$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial \mathbf{n}}=0, \ \text{on} \ \partial \Omega \times [0,T]$$
is the $L^2$-gradient flow of the total free energy $\mathcal{E}(\phi)$.

How to derive this?

Comment: Could you mention the references that make this definition ?

Answer (score 25):

Given an energy $\mathcal{E}(\phi)$, the associated gradient flow is given by the equation
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = - \frac{\partial \mathcal{E}}{\partial \phi}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In other words, $\phi$ decreases along the gradient of $\mathcal{E}$. The terminology stems from the 'finite dimensional' case, where a function $f(x,y,z)$ produces a vector field $V = \nabla f$, which is called its 'gradient vector field'. Then, as with any vector field, one can study the *flow* induced by that vector field, i.e. the flow of the dynamical system given by $\dot{x} = V(x)$.

In $(1)$, the notation $\frac{\partial \mathcal{E}}{\partial \phi}$ denotes the so-called *functional derivative* of $\mathcal{E}$ to $\phi$, which generalises the 'gradient' notion for functions. There exist multiple versions of the functional derivative, mainly because its definition depends on the function space on which $\mathcal{E}$ acts. Anyway, the idea is to perturb $\phi$ a bit, i.e. to substitute $\phi \to \phi + \delta \psi$ with $0 < \delta \ll 1$, and work out the resulting expression. In the Ginzburg-Landau case, you get
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{E}(\phi+\delta \psi) &= \int_\Omega F(\phi+\delta \psi) + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \left| \nabla \phi + \delta \nabla \psi\right|^2\,\text{d}\mathbf{x}\\
&= \int_\Omega F(\phi) + \delta F'(\phi)\,\psi + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \left| \nabla \phi\right|^2 + \epsilon^2 \delta \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \psi + \delta^2 \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\left|\nabla \psi\right|^2\,\text{d}\mathbf{x}\\
&= \mathcal{E}(\phi) + \delta \int_\Omega F'(\phi)\,\psi + \epsilon^2 \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \psi\,\text{d}\mathbf{x} + \mathcal{O}(\delta^2)\\
&= \mathcal{E}(\phi) + \delta \int_\Omega \left[F'(\phi) - \epsilon^2 \Delta \phi\right] \psi\,\text{d}\mathbf{x} + \int_{\delta \Omega}\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \psi\,\text{d}\mathbf{n} +  \mathcal{O}(\delta^2),
\end{align}
where the last equation was derived using [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). If you now assume that the gradient of $\phi$ vanishes at the boundary of $\Omega$, the integral over $\delta\Omega$ vanishes, and you're left with
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}(\phi+\delta \psi) - \mathcal{E}(\phi) = \delta \int_\Omega \left[F'(\phi) - \epsilon^2 \Delta \phi\right] \psi\,\text{d}\mathbf{x} = \delta \left\langle F'(\phi) - \epsilon^2 \Delta \phi,\psi\right\rangle_2
\end{equation}
up to terms of order $\delta^2$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the $L_2$ inner product over $\Omega$. The above is now interpreted as the *directional derivative* of $\mathcal{E}$ in the direction of $\psi$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
 \left\langle \frac{\partial \mathcal{E}}{\partial \phi},\psi\right\rangle_2 := \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{E}(\phi+\delta \psi)-\mathcal{E}(\phi)}{\delta} = \left\langle F'(\phi) - \epsilon^2 \Delta \phi,\psi\right\rangle_2,
\end{equation}
and therefore we see that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{E}}{\partial \phi} = F'(\phi) - \epsilon^2 \Delta \phi. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ now gives the Allen-Cahn equation.

Comment: May I ask if "Ricci flow as gradient flow" shown in the beginning of page 5 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211159.pdf  uses the same methodolgy as you have shown here?

Comment: Yes, see Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation].

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.