# minimization of a functional using lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I have some trouble in understanding the origin of lagrange multipliers for minimization of a functional with some constraints. I would appreciate if anyone could clarify this in detail.

The functional in my expression is given by,

$$
\tag{1}
F(\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3) = \int_{\Omega} \left(\Sigma_1 |\nabla \phi_1|^2 + \Sigma_2 |\nabla \phi_2|^2 + \Sigma_3 |\nabla \phi_3|^2 ​\right) d\Omega + \int_{\partial \Omega} \psi^s ds
$$

with $\psi^s = \sigma_1 (3\phi_1^2 - 2\phi_1^3) + \sigma_2 (3\phi_2^2 - 2\phi_2^3) + \sigma_3 (3\phi_3^2 - 2\phi_3^3)$. Here, $\Sigma_i, \sigma_i \ \forall \ i = 1,2,3$ are constants. $F$ has to be minimized with the constraint
$$
\tag{2}
\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 = 1
$$

Minimization of this functional is performed using [variational derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687804/what-is-the-l2-gradient-flow) and I am just interested in the boundary terms along $\partial \Omega$. This yields

$$
\tag{3}
2 \Sigma_1 \nabla \phi_1 \cdot \mathbf{n} + 6 \sigma_1 \phi_1 (1 - \phi_1) - \Gamma_1 = 0 \\
2 \Sigma_2 \nabla \phi_2 \cdot \mathbf{n} + 6 \sigma_2 \phi_2 (1 - \phi_2) - \Gamma_2 = 0 \\
2 \Sigma_3 \nabla \phi_3 \cdot \mathbf{n} + 6 \sigma_3 \phi_3 (1 - \phi_3) - \Gamma_3 = 0
$$

I do understand the procedure of this minimization, but the article I refer directly uses different lagrange multipliers $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_3$ in Eq. (3).

I do understand that Eq. (3) would satisfy the constraint (2) when

$$
\tag{4}
6 \frac{\sigma_1}{\Sigma_1} \phi_1 (1 - \phi_1) + 6 \frac{\sigma_2}{\Sigma_2} \phi_2 (1 - \phi_2) + 6 \frac{\sigma_3}{\Sigma_3} \phi_3 (1 - \phi_3) - \frac{\Gamma_1}{\Sigma_1} - \frac{\Gamma_2}{\Sigma_2} - \frac{\Gamma_3}{\Sigma_3} = 0
$$

An additional constraint which needs to be satisfied in my case is

$$
\tag{5}
\Gamma_1|_{\phi_1 = 0} = 0, \Gamma_2|_{\phi_2 = 0} = 0, \Gamma_3|_{\phi_3 = 0} = 0.
$$

I also understand that if the constraint (5) was absent, this problem could be easily solved by adding the term $\int_{\partial \Omega} \Gamma (\phi_1 + \phi_2 + \phi_3 - 1)$ to Eq. (1) such that $\Gamma_1 = \Gamma_2 = \Gamma_3 = \Gamma$. In that case, Eq. (3) could be easily manipulated to yield an expression of $\Gamma$. What I don't understand is how $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \Gamma_3$ need to be added to the functional in (1) to yield Eq. (3).